# Set of vectors generates a vector space V

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was given this question today, which I am having some difficulty answering (with discrete logic):

> Explain what it means that a set of vectors generates a vector space V.

How do I go about elaborately explaining this? I cannot seem to find a good definition of 'generates'.. does this mean the same thing as span?

Thank you!

Comment: It means that every vector $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the vectors that generate (or span) the vector space.

Comment: What do you mean by "set of vectors"?What is the base field for your vector space?

Comment: I believe in the context of the question, it could be assumed that we are in any arbitrary field $F.$

Answer (score -1):

What you have to show is that the set of all linear combination of the given vectors satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

For example, you need to show that it is nonempty, closed under addition and scalar multiplication, the existence of a zero vector and the additive inverse, and the other axioms.